# Update the column data based on the data in the other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My Table looks like

```
Start_Date    End_Date     Q1   Q2     Q3    Q4
-------------------------------------------------   
01/01/2020    04/12/2020                       

For Q1 Date Range is between 1/1/2020     03/31/2020 
For Q2 Date Range is between 4/1/2020     06/30/2020 
For Q3 Date Range is between 7/1/2020     9/30/2020 
For Q4 Date Range is between 10/1/2020    12/31/2020
```

I want to fill the columns Q1,Q2 ,Q3,Q4 with the working days(Mon-Fri) based on the start date and End Date.

I want to update Q1 as 65(working days between 1/1/2020 - 03/31/2020 ) Q2 as 8 (working days between 04/1/2020 - 04/12/2020 ).

```
Start_Date    End_Date     Q1   Q2     Q3    Q4
-------------------------------------------------   
10/01/2020     01/15/2021  65   8
```

I have the query to calculate the working days as  below:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '04/01/2020'
SET @EndDate = '04/12/2020'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I want to know, how to update the table Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 values.

Comment: How do you know the number of "working days"?  Do you have a calendar table somewhere?  What happens when the time span includes more than one year?

Comment: Do you need consider holidays too? This clearly needs calendar table with additional info.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - Number of working days are calculated from Mon to Fri. Not considering the holidays, I need a query to calculate Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 values.  If it includes more than a year, same rule applies. Q1 is (Jan,Feb,Mar) Q2(Apr,May,June) Q3(Jul,Aug,Sep) Q4(Oct,Nov,Dec).

Comment: @Arvo Any Help on this?